# Both expressions are TRUE

Tags: c

In the first block of code both conditions hold TRUE. In second, the first holds true and the other holds false.

```
int8_t i8 = -2;
uint16_t ui16 = i8;
if(ui16 == -2)       //this is TRUE
if(ui16 == 65534)    //this is TRUE as well
```

And This is the second scenario:

```
int8_t i8 = -2;
int16_t i16 = i8;
if(i16 == -2)       //this is TRUE
if(i16 == 65534)    //this is NOT TRUE !!!
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: `65534` is of type `int` - if `int` is larger than `int16_t` then `i16` is beeing promoted to `int` with sign extension

Comment: Is your question "why is this happening?"?

Comment: There are lots of [conversions and promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) going on here that you need to be aware of.

Comment: Looks like you are using a 16 bit compiler. Anyway, you are using values outside their ranges, so (1) you are living dangerously, and (2) a careful reading of the C standard, especially promotion rules, will explain everything.

Comment: Also, it might be good to know about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (to understand why `-2 == 65534`)

Comment: In order to be a most effective C programmer you'll always want to try to keep in mind what's happening in the machine code that's generated when you write your source and compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `-2` fits into `int16_t` whereas `-2` is converted to unsigned in `uint16_t`.

This is well-defined behaviour.

*from ISO/IEC 9899 (C99 standard working draft):*

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>     ...
>   2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>49)</sup>
>   ...
>   <sup>49)</sup> The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression

So if I do:

```
uint16_t i = -2;
```

the compiler *should* do:

```
i = -2 + (USHRT_MAX + 1);
```

or

```
i = -2 - (USHRT_MAX + 1);
```

until we get a value storable within 16 bits with no sign bit.

Not dependent on the rank of `-2`, but the mathematical value.

In your case this should be: `65534`

[Which it is with gcc.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b7a900860326752)
[C++ follows the same rules for signed conversions]

In your second section of code you are simply assigning a lower rank value to a higher rank variable.

e.g. using more bits of precision to store the same number.

When you check against `i16 == 65534` you are invoking this part of the standard from the same section:

> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

because `65534` is not storable in 15 bits and a sign bit (2<sup>15</sup> - 1).

So invoking *implementation* defined behaviour.

Relying on the return value of this is just as bad as relying on *undefined* behaviour unless you're a compiler developer.

Answer (score 1):

In C, unsigned integers always behave according to modular (clock-face) arithmetic, but signed integers only sometimes, unreliably do.

Generally speaking, expecting one number to equal a different number is nonsense. You shouldn't write programs that way. If you want a number like `-2` to behave like a positive unsigned value, you should explicitly write a cast like `(uint16_t) -2`. Otherwise, there are many things that could go wrong.